# chosen harvesthq apply specific width to different dropdown based on id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width, jquery-chosen

I am adding new feature to already running project and I need to use chosen dropdown for one of the dropdown. This feature will be added to navbar of site so the css will be applied globaly on entire site.

For Example:

```
<select id='mydropdown' name='mydropdown' multiple='true' class='chosen-select-dsbrd'>
```

Now I need to give this select dropdown a custom width and as per other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16960690/chosen-harvesthq-resize-width-dynamically/28277105) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25983906/width-of-chosen-dropdowns-near-zero-when-starting-in-collapsed-bootstrap-accordi) , [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316617/chosen-select-width-problems) I tried:

```
 .chosen-container .chosen-container-multi {
        width: 460px !important;
    }
```

and

```
.chosen-select-dsbrd {
width: 460px !important;
}
```

The problem is, previous developers were using the chosen for their own features, so how can I change width of my dropdown without disturbing their dropdowns. As of now if I change css using above code it changes all chosen dropdown width across site. Any help appreciated, thanks in advance.

Edit: I have tried with ID, its not working as chosen dynamically adds `display: none` to my select dropdown and appends `<div>` with their dropdown code

Comment: If you only want to affect that specific `select` then target it by using the `id` selector in your CSS instead of the generic class names

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan its not working, im trying that with jquery

Comment: Why use jQuery? Just plain CSS as in your examples will work

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan when i inspect the code, it is getting added to select dropdown with id properly, but chosen is hidding it and appending custom div with their dropdown code with classes I added in question, so its not working that way

Comment: Ok, so try adding a custom class just to this element only and target that

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thats the thing, can't do that as it affects other chosen dropdown across site

Comment: How does putting a class on *this element only* affect all the others in the site?